# Bouncing burger menu

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I need to realize burger menu with **bouncing meatball effect or water drop** (name it what as you want) something like [**that**](https://dribbble.com/shots/1708213-floating-hamburger).

I don't need all effects from there, I need only this water drop effect with explanations.

Here's my code.

As you see there is nothing incomprehensible here.

Simple `jQuery` with `toggle` method `CSS` with some `mediaqueries` for small screen show or hide burger ..

```js
$(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("ul.menu li").slideToggle('fast');
})
```

```css
body {
  background: lightblue !important;
  height: 1000px;
}

.header {
  height: 57px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
  filter: url("#goo");
}
.header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.header h1 a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: auto;
  height: 57px;
}
.header h1 a img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 57px;
}
.header .menu-trigger {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 50;
}
.header .menu-trigger span {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.header .menu-trigger span:after {
  top: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.header .menu-trigger span:before {
  top: -6px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.header nav {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header nav .menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  height: 57px;
  line-height: 3.5;
}
.header nav .menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active span {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.active span:after {
  top: -1px !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.active span:before {
  top: -1px !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header .menu-trigger span, .header .menu-trigger span:after, .header .menu-trigger span:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="menu-trigger">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="logo clearfix"><a href="#">Brand</a></h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Four</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Five</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Six</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

 <svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="goo"> 
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" result="blur"/> 
                <feColorMatrix in="blur" 
                mode="matrix" 
                values="1 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 0 0 0 
                0 0 1 0 0 
                0 0 0 18 -8" result="goo"/> 
                <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo"/> 
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: _“As you see there is nothing incomprehensible here.”_ - I don’t see any attempt or even presentation of your research results either … http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @CBroe my code  It's not this an attempt?

Comment: Hope this helps https://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticSVGElements/button.html

Comment: @Duck_dragon thanks

Comment: @CBroe I will add the attempt.Hope then you will remove your'e downvote

Comment: _“my code It's not this an attempt?”_ - well where exactly is anything water-droppy in that now …?

Comment: @CBroe look now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've made, I hope it will suit you.

We will be using CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) to achieve this result.

Also, we will need some JavaScript to toggle the class.

---

### Step by step answer:

I got away using the [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property, here how:

1. Create a square

   ```css
   #droplet {
     background-color: lightblue;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px #1a1a1a;
     width: 75px;
     height: 75px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="droplet"></div>
   ```
2. then change the radius of each border to control their shape. You can use border-radius which controls  all four corners: `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius`, `border-bottom-right-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`. You can set the four values on a single line like so:

   ```
   border-radius: topLeft topRight bottomRight bottomLeft;
   ```

   The `border-radius` will have an effect when its value is between `0` and half of the width (or height) of the box). In the example below `0px` is a sharp corner while `40px` is a rounded corner. That's what we are looking for for our droplet.

   Here's an example:

   ```css
   #droplet {
     background-color: lightblue;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px #1a1a1a;
     width: 75px;
     height: 75px;
     border-radius: 5px 10px 20px 40px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="droplet"></div>
   ```
3. Now we need to create some different shapes called keyframes that will represent our animation. The other frames will be calculated from these keyframes.

   ```css
   .droplet {
     background-color: lightblue;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px #1a1a1a;
     width: 75px;
     height: 75px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 20px;
   }

   #droplet1 {
     border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   #droplet2 {
     border-radius: 0px 40px 30px 40px;
     transform: rotate(45deg);
   }
   #droplet3 {
     border-radius: 37px 37.5px 37.5px 37.5px;
     transform: rotate(45deg);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="droplet" id="droplet1"></div>
   <div class="droplet" id="droplet2"></div>
   <div class="droplet" id="droplet3"></div>
   ```
4. We can link everything by creating a new keyframe with CSS the [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) syntax.

   > The `@keyframes` CSS at-rule controls the intermediate steps in a CSS animation sequence by defining styles for keyframes (or waypoints) along the animation sequence. This gives more control over the intermediate steps of the animation sequence than transitions.

   You can specify those steps with percentage values. Here I have defined the animation `droplet`. I have added a lot more properties to make it look better:

   ```
   @keyframes droplet {
     0% {
       top: 10px;
       border-top-left-radius: 0px;
       border-top-right-radius: 0px;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
       transform: rotate(0deg);
     }
     25% {
       top: 10px;
       border-top-left-radius: 0px;
       border-top-right-radius: 40px;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
     }
     30% {
       transform: rotate(45deg);
     }
     60% {
       top: 34px;
     }
     100% {
       top: 15px;
       border-top-left-radius: 37px;
       border-top-right-radius: 37.5px;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 37.5px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 37.5px;
       transform: rotate(45deg);
     }
   }
   ```
5. We will create a separate class dedicated to animating the element: `.active`:

   ```
   .active {
     animation: droplet 0.5s forwards;
                   ↑      ↑       ↑
                 name  duration  mode  
   }
   ```

   makes it so that:

   > The element will retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe.

   Whatever element has the class name `active` will animate with the keyframes defined above.
6. Now we need to add the JavaScript code that will toggle the animation on and off:

   ```
   $('#droplet').click(function() {

     $(this).toggleClass('active');

   });
   ```

That's about all there is to it. To finish off I added the actual hamburger icon: `#burger` and attached a different animation on it to make sure it is horizontal at all times (`#droplet` is rotating during the animation).

---

### Version 1: burger animation

```js
$('#droplet').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(this).children().first().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
#burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 14px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#burger > div {
  background-color: #575757;
  width: 47px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 9px 0;
}

#droplet {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px #1a1a1a;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

#droplet.active {
  animation: droplet 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes droplet {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  60% {
    top: 34px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 37px;
    border-top-right-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 37.5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

#burger.active {
  animation: burger 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes burger {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="droplet">
  <div id="burger"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

---

### Version 2: burger separates from main header

```js
$('#droplet').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#menu > div').toggleClass('active');
  $('#burger').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 14px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#burger > div {
  background-color: #575757;
  width: 47px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 9px 0;
}
#droplet {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

#droplet.active {
  animation: droplet 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes droplet {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  60% {
    top: 34px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 37px;
    border-top-right-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 37.5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

#burger.active {
  animation: burger 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes burger {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#menu > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
  top: 98px;
 height: 200px;
 background: pink;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
#menu > div.active {
  animation: menu 0.2s forwards;
  
}

@keyframes menu {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 98px;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 500px / 50px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"><div></div></div>
<div id="droplet">
  <div id="burger"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

### Version 3: fixed menu, animation triggered by scrolling

```js
const toggleAnimation = () => {

  $('#droplet').toggleClass('active');
  $('#menu').toggleClass('active');
  $('#burger').toggleClass('active');
  
}


let below = false;
$(window).scroll(() => {

  const Ypos = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  if(Ypos > 50 && !below) {
  
    below = true;
    toggleAnimation();
    
  } else if(Ypos < 50 && below) {
  
    below = false;
    toggleAnimation();
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.v-space {
  height: 120px;
}
#burger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 14px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#burger > div {
  background-color: #575757;
  width: 47px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 9px 0;
}
#droplet {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  right: 60px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

#droplet.active {
  animation: droplet 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes droplet {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  60% {
    top: 34px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 37px;
    border-top-right-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 37.5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 37.5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

#burger.active {
  animation: burger 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes burger {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#menu > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 98px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 0px;
}
#menu.active > div {
  animation: menuCover 0.2s forwards;
}
#menu.active {
  animation: menu 0.2s forwards;
}
@keyframes menu {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes menuCover {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 98px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 500px / 50px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu"><div></div></div>
<div id="droplet">
  <div id="burger"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="v-space"></div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean odio metus, sollicitudin quis scelerisque eu, interdum non nisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi ultricies lacus ut felis fermentum, non malesuada nunc ornare. Quisque laoreet vestibulum varius. Morbi efficitur nisi in nisl rutrum, ac pretium magna vulputate. In est libero, commodo et nisi tristique, faucibus fringilla tortor. Donec sed ornare felis, vitae bibendum dui. Nulla mi nulla, vestibulum sed ullamcorper ut, venenatis at libero. In placerat odio id sapien blandit, a consectetur ligula cursus. Sed cursus dictum ipsum a ultricies.

Morbi in odio sagittis, congue orci vel, euismod nisi. Suspendisse sit amet imperdiet nulla. Nullam sollicitudin velit viverra, placerat felis sit amet, rhoncus turpis. Duis et neque malesuada, finibus massa id, ullamcorper dui. Morbi ut fringilla augue. Duis quam sem, lobortis sed gravida eu, sagittis a ex. Cras commodo bibendum tristique. Praesent in pulvinar eros, quis maximus magna. Etiam dui leo, ullamcorper in interdum at, dignissim in sem. Suspendisse ac urna mollis, feugiat eros nec, aliquam purus. Donec eget enim at enim interdum facilisis. Nam non consectetur enim. In non eros quis tortor auctor interdum.

Etiam id ipsum risus. Donec ut orci nulla. Duis lacinia, erat vitae maximus efficitur, lectus risus feugiat sem, in suscipit nibh enim efficitur nibh. Fusce sollicitudin lacinia lectus, non malesuada nisi rhoncus id. Sed id congue sem, sit amet tincidunt nulla. Etiam vitae mauris sapien. Aenean ornare volutpat libero sed interdum. Aenean placerat aliquet dolor, eleifend bibendum mi rutrum sit amet. Nullam eu lacus ornare, dapibus ante sit amet, vehicula enim. Vestibulum at euismod ex. Ut at vehicula purus, nec porttitor tellus. Vivamus consequat sapien eu est malesuada, quis varius est aliquet. Sed eu volutpat lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam varius, augue ac pretium commodo, turpis tellus commodo turpis, venenatis tristique velit odio sed quam. Phasellus tempor nisi eu massa elementum bibendum.

Sed ac egestas enim. Integer hendrerit, ligula sit amet viverra imperdiet, massa nunc consequat leo, sit amet ornare quam nisi sed elit. In pulvinar libero a ligula consectetur tincidunt. Proin fringilla turpis sagittis dolor facilisis imperdiet. In nec suscipit urna. Sed turpis justo, dapibus ac risus efficitur, lacinia suscipit nunc. Aliquam ex nisl, ultricies quis elit a, rutrum tempus metus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis consequat suscipit eleifend. Morbi a euismod augue. In facilisis lacus a est suscipit, non interdum dolor condimentum. Cras aliquet ornare diam sit amet laoreet. Aliquam sed enim varius, efficitur arcu id, tincidunt dui. Nulla scelerisque urna nec feugiat fermentum.

Suspendisse sit amet orci lacus. Pellentesque vitae ante finibus, volutpat risus et, posuere orci. Sed posuere tellus sem, sed pulvinar massa finibus ut. Duis tempor rutrum diam a vestibulum. Curabitur at libero eu urna imperdiet vehicula. Etiam aliquet maximus ipsum, eu lobortis lectus rhoncus eget. Suspendisse semper facilisis lectus. Curabitur non lectus a risus ullamcorper ultricies non pulvinar diam. Sed euismod imperdiet facilisis. Fusce sagittis nibh vel lorem accumsan fringilla.

Fusce ac leo lacus. Nullam dictum id orci nec semper. Nam non ultrices tellus. Curabitur felis erat, bibendum sit amet quam eu, luctus finibus leo. Nullam ac porta nibh, eget euismod mauris. Phasellus posuere enim sed tellus fermentum, nec vehicula nisi mattis. Vivamus elementum varius enim, vulputate dignissim enim iaculis sit amet.

Vivamus pellentesque, enim vitae porta pulvinar, eros turpis tempor mauris, in facilisis dui libero in purus. Nunc erat purus, tristique vitae ex non, commodo cursus purus. Nulla fermentum quam ac vestibulum facilisis. Duis semper nunc orci, non fringilla sem placerat ut. Mauris posuere eu urna a gravida. Nam ullamcorper, ligula a ultricies feugiat, mi ipsum viverra diam, vel aliquam velit mauris eu diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed magna dolor, malesuada at orci ut, vehicula dignissim dolor. In odio libero, vestibulum eu rhoncus eu, tempus sed diam.

Sed eget hendrerit elit, a tincidunt sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam facilisis nibh quis pulvinar condimentum. Ut interdum quam non mauris faucibus, a faucibus felis interdum. Maecenas porttitor, lorem vel fringilla semper, orci arcu varius justo, ut convallis tellus lectus et metus. Quisque porta dolor magna, ac convallis tortor egestas eu. Integer in ligula eget ipsum blandit interdum.

Cras viverra, dui finibus dictum scelerisque, quam arcu vehicula sapien, vel varius sem risus sed nulla. Cras sit amet lacus a quam vestibulum consequat et ut enim. Nunc vestibulum libero a nisi euismod tincidunt. Sed vel mollis risus. Cras convallis luctus enim sit amet suscipit. Vivamus egestas metus ut luctus consequat. Aliquam rutrum elit eu interdum consequat. Donec metus odio, sagittis sit amet bibendum nec, convallis nec nisl. Quisque eget nisl bibendum, fermentum mauris non, dictum quam. Nunc pretium faucibus risus sed pellentesque. Maecenas dictum sodales justo id rutrum. Cras vel feugiat turpis.

Quisque a malesuada nunc, non vulputate magna. Quisque ac leo consequat, auctor orci vitae, pulvinar tellus. Pellentesque euismod arcu a lacinia condimentum. Vestibulum et purus neque. Donec libero erat, auctor sed tempus et, auctor at nisl. In eu elit non turpis dapibus facilisis. Vestibulum sodales ex purus, ut ultricies risus mattis non. Donec id elementum nunc.</div>
```

Comment: ty  for the answer I give you +1 but if I don't get more exact answer I will accept your'e answer

Comment: All right Spectr, I have edited my answer with some tweaks (version 2), have a look.

Comment: Yup pretty almost look like in the link.But how I can realize this on position fixed.When scrollled down It must separate from header.İf you realize this İ accept your'e answer.

Comment: @Spectr You mean you would like the animation to be triggered when the user scrolls down (not on mouse click)?

Comment: Yes Of course .Like in the gif image that I gived the link.I need animation triggered when user scrolled down.

Comment: I'm waiting for you :)

Comment: Here you got, let me know what you think (version 3!)

Comment: Thank you to waste your'e time and energy to solve this problem this answer are amazing .I can not give your'e award .Stackoverflow need's more 7 hour's for this.I do it later .

Comment: No problem, I'm happy I could help. Don't worry I didn't waste my time. You won't believe how much I learnt answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my light-weight shot at it without much explanation since Ivan explained it pretty well:

1. [complementary CodePen](https://codepen.io/MiXT4PE/pen/VdgZyW) with some extra styling and features
2. basic functionality in snippet:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 100) 
    $("#drop").addClass("active");
  else if (scroll < 80) 
    $("#drop").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1d1e22;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 600px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0 5%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#drop {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 0 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#drop.active {
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: drop 0.3s forwards;
}

#drop > div {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#drop span {
  display: block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div id="drop" class="active">
      <div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I did not animate the navbar because you don't seem to care about it. Let me know if I misunderstood that part.

Comment: awesome ty  +1 from me .

Comment: @Spectr no problem! Be sure to check out the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MiXT4PE/pen/VdgZyW) for a more real-life implementation